# How to get a chart for memory usage in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-beanstalk

How to get memory chart in AWS EBS?
Lots of choice there but memory is not one of them.
The setup used includes a load balancer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default metrics you see are the ones visible by the hypervisor. Memory utilisation along with for example disk space utilisation is an OS-level metric, not hypervisor-level metric, and to capture it in CloudWatch you’ll have to install [**CloudWatch Agent**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on your instance. Then you’ll get access to many more metrics.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please clarify further. Am I correct that you stated that the way to get charts for os-level metrics in Elastic Beanstalk is by using CloudWatch? They can't be created in EB directly?